# Insert data into every record in table with condition, but auto populating apart of it.... I'll try and explain as best I can :-)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

So,

I know how to do the 1st part

```
insert into Table name (policy_id, target_type, target_id)
values
(16758, 7, 810) where target_type = 7
```

The thing is, that the `policy_id` will be different in every row

So, I want to populate the `policy_id` with the existing policy ID recursively through every record but insert the same data for `target_type` and `target_id` which are constant.

does that make sense to anyone :-)

TIA

Comment: There is NO `where` clause on an `INSERT` query. If you think about it logically it will be obvious

Comment: Still not completely sure what you are trying to achieve here, but did you intend to UPDATE existing rows or Create new rows

Comment: You probably need to use the UPDATE statement...Here is the documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: I want to add a new row, adding the current policy_id data, with the data stated in target_type and target_id

Comment: so, the existing would be for example...16758, 7, 810 and I want to add 1658, 9, 750

Comment: additionally, to every row that meets the condition, the new policy_id would need to be inserted into a new row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the idea is to duplicate some existing policy IDs, but with new values in other fields, is that right? Providing a sample of the existing data and then a matching sample of the expected result of your query would have helped us a lot to understand precisely what you mean.

Based on what you *have* told us, I suspect you're looking for `INSERT...SELECT` syntax, and you probably want a query something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table_name (policy_id, target_type, target_id)
SELECT policy_id, 7, 810
FROM Table_name 
WHERE target_type = 7
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html, 
 and http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-into-select/ for more info.

---

P.S. you probably didn't mean "recursively", that was a bit confusing. [Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) is quite a specific thing in programming and it doesn't really apply to SQL queries.

Comment: I'll give that a whirl.... Thanks for the assistance, and I'll mind my expressions going forward ;-)

Comment: @RobMcAndrew No problem. If it works, please don't forget to come back and mark the answer as "accepted" (click the tick mark next to it so it turns green), so that other readers know the answer was useful - thanks :-)

Comment: Mate, That worked a TREAT!!!! Also, I'd like to state that this was my 1st ever post on this forum... I did look for a way to post a screenshot... I'll try and do better in future.. Thanks for your help pal!

Comment: @RobMcAndrew Don't worry, your post was far better than many...only a little bit of info missing which would have added some extra clarity, that's all. P.S. For future reference, if you ask things again, no-one will want screenshots of your data, so don't worry about adding those...they'll want it copied and pasted into the question as a table so they can search it, copy it, use it in demos / answers etc :-)